# Styling an Admin Grid's Edit Form

Tags: adminhtml, grid, css

I'm working in Module/Block/Adminhtml/Sqlreport/Edit/Form.php

I have some code like this:

```
$fieldset->addField("columnHeader", 'text', array(
    'name'      => 'columnHeader',
    'label'     => 'Header',
));
```

How can I add CSS styling to this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer while asking it! Simply add a 'class' field to the array.  It would change my above code to the following:

```
$fieldset->addField("columnHeader", 'text', array(
   'name'      => 'columnHeader',
   'label'     => 'Header',
   'class'     => 'sqlreport_header',
));
```